# How do i get the latest group in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Here is a dummy test i made up (oops i forgot id). I'd like to write one query which will return the higest grp # in each group id. Which in this case is the last 2 rows unless i delete the last row. Then it'd be the last row and 2nd row. Anyways i have no idea how to write the query w/o using a subquery and its been a while that i forgot how to write a subquery (thats a good thing right?)

```
CREATE TABLE example ( gid INT, grp INT, data VARCHAR(100) );
--
mysql> select * from example;
+------+------+------+
| gid  | grp  | data |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | a    |
|    1 |    2 | a    |
|    2 |    1 | a    |
|    2 |    2 | a    |
|    1 |    5 | a    |
+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select gid,max(grp)as 'higest_grp' from example group by gid
```

Comment: i don't think this is right. it will return the first gid in the group and not the maximum one.

Comment: after creating 'example' table using above create table query use following query to insert data
INSERT INTO `example` (`gid`, `grp`, `data`) VALUES
 (1, 1, 'a'),
 (1, 2, 'a'),
 (2, 1, 'a'),
 (2, 2, 'a'),
 (1, 5, 'a');

Then try to execute my above query

Comment: @Gustonez It will return ALL `gid`'s, not just the first (or maximum) one.

Comment: yeah but what about the data?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT gid, MAX(grp) FROM example GROUP BY gid
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the correct way to retrieve the correct `data` for each row.

```
SELECT `gid`, `grp`, `data` FROM `example` 
WHERE `grp` IN (SELECT MAX(t2.`grp`) FROM `example` t2 GROUP BY `gid`) 
GROUP BY `gid`
```